# How to add a OneNote notebook tab to Teams channel using Graph API and PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, onenote

I'm trying to add a tab containing a OneNote notebook into my MS Teams channel using Graph API.
I found this [usefull blog post](http://laurentschoenaers.be/2020/06/11/use-microsoft-graph-to-add-a-notebook-tab-to-a-team/) that is explaining how to do this. Unofortunetely I did not manage to go to the end.
I'm stuck to the step when he is creating a OneNote in the Teams, whatever that means.

Here is a picture of my Microsoft Graph Explorer windows:

[image]

FYI my Request body section contains the following code :

```
{
    "displayName": "OneNote"
}
```

Here is my PowerShell. The variables that are not initialized have actual values (personnal or irrelevant for this post). They are properly defined because i'm getting all I want to. Only the last request invocation is not working.

```
$graphAPIUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/"
$teamTitle = "My teams"

# Connecting to AzureAD Services
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $creds

# Connecting to Graph API services
Connect-PnPOnline -ClientId $GraphAppId -ClientSecret $GraphAppSecret -AADDomain $AADDomain

# Getting access token
$token = Get-PnPGraphAccessToken
$headers = @{
    "Authorization"="Bearer " + $token;
    "Content-Type"= "application/json";
    "Content-length" = 200;
}

# Getting current team group ID
$getAllGroupsRequest = "$($graphAPIUrl)groups"
$groups = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $getAllGroupsRequest -Headers $headers -Method "GET"
$groupId = ($groups.value | Where-Object displayName -eq $teamTitle).id

# Getting site collection ID
$getRootSiteInfoRequest = "$($graphAPIUrl)groups/$($groupId)/sites/root"
$siteCollectionInfos = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $getRootSiteInfoRequest -Headers $headers -Method "GET"

# Getting site ID
$siteCollectionId = (($siteCollectionInfos.value).id -Split ",")[1]
$siteId = (($siteCollectionInfos.value).id -Split ",")[2]

# Creating the notebook in teams
$createNoteBookRequest = "$($graphAPIUrl)groups/$($groupId)/onenote/notebooks"
$body = @{
    "displayName" = "OneNote"
}
$formatedBody = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $body
$createdGroup = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $getRootSiteInfoRequest -Headers $headers -Method "POST" -Body $body
```

When I launch the snippet above I'm getting the following message:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : You must write ContentLength bytes to the request stream before calling [Begin]GetResponse
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Invoke-RestMethod is fine for the "GET" operations, but it seems like it's not great for POST ones, so try convert the last line of what you posted above, the Invoke-WebRequest with a "body", to

```
$createdGroup = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri -Headers $headers -ContentType 'application/json' -Method "POST" -Body $body
```

Comment: I dont understand your answer. I do have a body in my request already.

Comment: ah, my mistake - wasn't reading my own answer properly! The "Invoke-RestMethod" is meant to change to "Invoke-WebRequest" - see updated answer

Comment: Yes. After applying your tip, I still get the same error message.

Comment: it's more work, but you can try use the webclient directly, that powers both of these commands - see here for more: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/0c268c7e-674c-49bc-9933-a87a95f8f44c/powershell-webclientuploadfile?forum=winserverpowershell