# Use OneNote Template when creating a Teams Template

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate, microsoft-graph-teams, onenote, power-automate-custom-connector

OK, try to follow me...

My goal is to be able to create teams based on a template and using a OneNote template. This template has 3 (custom) channels and a OneNote Notebook...each of the channels has a tab to the Notebook and is linked to their respective section. The Image below shows exactly how the Team and channels should look.

[image: Team Setup]

I'm still exploring Teams Admin and I cannot see how to add the OneNote template to my team. I have added OneNote as a Tab/App for my custom Team Template but cannot figure out a way to copy over a OneNote notebook for use in each channel. Is this possible or do I need to go another route, such as Power Automate and Graph?

[image]

I did create a Flow in the meantime but I have to go back and delete the wiki tabs and add the OneNote tabs and connect the sections to each channel after it runs. It works but not as automated as I would like. Any advice would be helpful :D

[image: Flow Part 1]
[image: Flow Part 2]
[image: Flow Part 3]
[image: Flow Part 4]

Comment: You've clearly done all the hard work in your Flow already. If it ain't broke...

Comment: Please check these links for your reference - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63815185/how-to-add-a-onenote-notebook-tab-to-teams-channel-using-graph-api-and-powershel, [Create and add a OneNote tab to your Microsoft Teams team channel using Power Automate + Graph API](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-pnp-blog/create-and-add-a-onenote-tab-to-your-microsoft-teams-team/ba-p/2162502), [Configuring the built-in tab types in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-configuring-builtin-tabs?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5003326),